# Howto: Owner rendered in ownee react

Tags: reactjs

```
var A = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <B>
                <h1>Title</h1>
            </B>
        );
    }
});
```

Child:

```
var B = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                // Where A should be....
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

In the example above, A is being rendered inbetween B.

What's currently happening is B is being rendered from A correctly, but the `<h1>Title</h1>` is not being added.  It ends the div and nothing shows up in-between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably this:

```
var B = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Strictly speaking, `<B>` does NOT render `<A>` (because this would cause an endless loop). Instead, `<B>` renders all `children` that were passed on as props from `<A>`. In your case, this is the `<h1>`.

PS, the documentation on this [can be found here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#children) (thank you @Kujira for the link)

Comment: Cool, this works.  Really poor documentation on this behavior.  Was looking at this for a while now.  Thanks!

Comment: @JustinWarner [Here's the documentation that you were looking for](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#children).